# Search box active when visiting website.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a search box that I would like to make active when the customer visits my web page.

My HTML is:

```
<form class="form-search top-search" action="Search.aspx" onsubmit="return validateSearch(this);" method="GET">
<input type="text" class="input-medium search-query yui-ac-input" name="ss" id="ss" placeholder="Search and find it fast" title="Search and find it fast" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value = 'Search and find it fast'; }" onfocus="if ((this.value == 'Search and find it fast')||(this.value == 'Search and find it fast')) { this.value = ''; }" onkeypress="if ((this.value == 'Please enter a keyword or item #')||(this.value == 'Search and find it fast')) { this.value = ''; } else{ document.getElementsByName('ss')[0].style.color='black'; }" autocomplete="off">
<input type="submit" title="Search" class="btn btn-orange SearchButton" value="Search">
</form>
```

I'm just wanting to default the user into the field, like how Amazon defaults you into their search box.

Comment: what is active means?

Comment: As in, defaults into the Search field upon page load. But only for the home page. Wouldn't make sense on product pages and such, because if the user is on a product page then they've likely found what they're looking for. Sound logic, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure Javascript solution, works IE6+ and any other browser.

Put this before body end tag

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var obj = document.getElementById("ss");
    obj.focus(); 
  </script>
```

On browsers, that support html5, you can use autofocus attribute inside input.

```
<input autofocus type="text" class="input-medium search-query yui-ac-input" name="ss" id="ss" placeholder="Search and find it fast" title="Search and find it fast" autocomplete="off" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the HTML5 [autofocus](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp) attribute:

```
<input type="text" autofocus>
```

Comment: Just a side note, the autofocus attribute is HTML5

Comment: While I do use the Modernizr.js on my page to provide HTML5 / CSS3 support, I am unsure if this is supported with it.

Comment: take a look at the browser support: http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/02-autofocus.html

Comment: @chrisツ Right, but what I'm wondering is, would my use of the Modernizr.js script inject support of autofocus?

Comment: I am not an expert, but I think modernizer only detects if your browser supports or supports not these features. Correct me if Iam wrong!

Answer (score 2):

You can use .focus() to focus the input

```
$(function () {
    $('#ss').focus();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kg6J3/)

Comment: Is there a way to only do this on page load on my home page? From what I'm seeing, Amazon only does it when you visit the home page.

Comment: @user2433689 like epascarello said, put the script in your home page

Comment: @MLeFevre hmm weird, i'll update the answer if i find a solution for that

Comment: @Anton it works on FF just that FF doesn't seem to allow setting focus on element inside iframe, or maybe it is more specific issue relative to jsFiddle, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Kg6J3/show

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of these options After Page Load.

```
$('#ss').focus();

$('#ss').select();

$('#ss').trigger('focus');

$('#ss').trigger('click');
```

For Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#ss').trigger('click');
});
```